# How to adjust wallpaper size

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, wallpaper

I am trying to make wallpaper aplication .Iam able to set the wallpaper but not able to set the wallpaper of its real size.The application is like when ever the user click on the image from the GridView it will be set as the wallpaper.Here is the code`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Integer[] imagesIDs   ={
R.drawable.img8};
Bitmap goal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic"+(position+1)+"selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goal= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imagesIDs[position]);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(goal);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}


private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        context=c;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesIDs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView ==null){
            imageView =new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }
        else{
            imageView=(ImageView)convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(imagesIDs[position]);
        return imageView;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have applied center crop to the image view

`imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);`

Try `FIT_XY` instead CENTER_CROP

Note: FIT_XY will make change in aspect ratio of your image. check [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for more.

Comment: I want the wallpaper to fit the screen.But as per your code it just fit the image of the GridView

Answer (score -1):

In the manifest file, Take the user-permision SET WALLPAPER SIZE HINTS and this will do the work